# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded solution

Tags: python, pandas, recursion

I need help on how to deal with the recursion depth error. I am getting this error when I try to replace NaN values with the median (due to outliers in a single column), using the below mentioned code,

```
app_data['AMT_REQ_CREDIT_BUREAU_YEAR'].fillna(app_data['AMT_REQ_CREDIT_BUREAU_YEAR'].median, inplace = True)
```

- The shape of the data is (307511, 18)
- The missing values in the
  column AMT_REQ_CREDIT_BUREAU_YEAR are 41519

How do I fix the error I'm getting? RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`median()` is a function. You passed a function,  not a function result as you issed the `()`

```
app_data = pd.DataFrame({"DATE":d, 
                         "AMT_REQ_CREDIT_BUREAU_YEAR":
                         [i.year if random.randint(0,3)<2 else np.nan for i in d]})

fillval = app_data['AMT_REQ_CREDIT_BUREAU_YEAR'].median()
app_data['AMT_REQ_CREDIT_BUREAU_YEAR'].fillna(app_data['AMT_REQ_CREDIT_BUREAU_YEAR'].median(), inplace = True)
app_data
```

Comment: Thank you @Rob Raymond. But where have you used the 'fillval' that you created?

Comment: just me experimenting...  not needed

Comment: Got it! Thank you, this helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps somebody else -

I faced the same error while deep copying a FileObject in Flask:

```
file_blob = copy.deepcopy(file_object)
```

Which threw the error:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

**Solution:** Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3323013/8788977) answer, add the below line at the top of your script:

```
sys.setrecursionlimit(1500)
```